# In what frame of reference are the Euler and Lagrange time derivatives taken in?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, differentiation

In what frame of reference are the [Euler and Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_and_Eulerian_specification_of_the_flow_field) time derivatives taken in?

I am beginning to study fluid mechanics, and there is a conceptual problem that I just can't shake. If you have a field of quantity $F(r,t)$, then computing the total time derivative would result in:

$$\frac{DF}{Dt} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial r}\frac{dr}{dt}.$$

Given that the lowercase $d$'s represent partial derivatives and that $r$ is explicitly time dependent so that $F$ has both an explicit and implicit dependence on time. I understand that this is the Lagrangian frame, where we focus on the movement of a single fluid parcel through a system, which changes its position throughout time as observed from an observer at rest. However, textbooks and online resources also define $DF/Dt$ to be the rate of change of quantity $F$ as observed from the moving fluid parcel (which is at rest according to an observer moving with the parcel). This doesn't make sense to me, because if we were to take velocity for instance, in the fluid parcel's frame of reference it would be at rest, so $Dv/Dt$ would be zero. However, this is not the case as $$Dv/Dt = dv/dt + dv/dr*dr/dt.$$ From my understanding, $DF/Dt$ is the rate of change of quantity $F$ w.r.t. time according to an observer at rest, however apparently the opposite is true. I know that the material derivative is used in Newton's laws, which are valid for inertial reference frames, so my understanding is further blurred. I am sure there is something wrong with my understanding so if someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to enter mathematical 
expressions on Physics SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is based on information from the textbooks Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot and Mechanics, by Symon. Consider the variation of pressure, p, in a flowing fluid.  To apply the laws of mechanics we observe the pressure following a fixed mass of fluid, that is we follow the mass as it flows with velocity $\vec v$; this is the Lagrangian viewpoint.  We can also observe the pressure from a fixed point in space; this is the Eulerian viewpoint.

From the Lagrangian viewpoint ${dp \over dt} = {\partial p \over dt} + {\partial p \over dx}{dx \over dt} +  {\partial p \over dy}{dy \over dt} + {\partial p \over dz}{dz \over dt}$ where ${dx \over dt}, {dy \over dt}, {dz \over dt}$ are the components of the fluid velocity.  We are following the fluid motion from an inertial frame. That is, we are watching the motion of a fixed mass of fluid as it moves from an inertial frame; we are not following the motion from a frame moving with the fluid. In the frame moving with the fluid the velocity is zero.

From the Eulerain viewpoint, we evaluate ${\partial p \over dt}$, the variation of pressure at a fixed position.

Both viewpoints use an inertial frame.  We could use a frame moving with the fluid; in general, this is a non-inertial frame and fictitious forces must also be considered in such a frame.

Comment: Thank you for the response! This makes sense to me, I think I was getting confused with the wording in the following sentence "DF/Dt is the rate of change of a local variable F that would be measured by an observer moving with the fluid." I took that to mean that the Lagrangian derivative was calculated in a frame of reference moving with the fluid, but I see I have misunderstood that (I think?). Could you possibly confirm this? Thanks.

Comment: The Lagrangian viewpoint is not in a frame of reference moving with the fluid; it is in an inertial frame following the moving fluid.  I agree with you that the wording used in many discussions is confusing.